# XPages headTag 'bookmark' icon - File does not exist because of proxy routing

Tags: proxy, icons, xpages, favicon

My XPage headTag code works correctly within the firewall. Because users will access this database through a proxy, the proxy is causing a problem with my icon/bookmark icons. This error appears in the logs:

File does not exist: C:/www/docs/ttt/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png where 'ttt' will direct you to the Domino server 'path' below.

The path on our Domino server is: /sss/database.nsf/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png

The png files are in my Image Resources. I thought that using the headTag with the href parameter and png filename would do the trick especially since the images are in the database. Do I need to hard-code the path above? Or how do I dynamically code? Or is there a different approach altogether? THANKS! Kendra

In HTML I might do this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png" />
```

In headTag in XPages Resources I am doing this:

```
<xp:headTag tagName="link" loaded="true" rendered="true">
            <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="rel" value="apple-touch-icon"
                    loaded="true">
                </xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter name="href" value="AppIcon.png"></xp:parameter>
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
        <xp:headTag tagName="link" rendered="true" loaded="true">
            <xp:this.attributes>
                <xp:parameter name="rel" value="apple-touch-icon"></xp:parameter>
                <xp:parameter value="72x72" name="sizes"></xp:parameter>
                <xp:parameter name="href"
                    value="touch-icon-ipad.png">
                </xp:parameter>
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
        <xp:headTag tagName="link" rendered="true" loaded="true">
            <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="rel" value="apple-touch-icon"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter value="57x57" name="sizes"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter name="href" value="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"></xp:parameter>
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
        <xp:headTag tagName="link" rendered="true" loaded="true">
            <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="rel" value="apple-touch-icon"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter value="114x114" name="sizes"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter name="href" value="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
            </xp:parameter>
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
        <xp:headTag tagName="link" rendered="true" loaded="true">
            <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="rel" value="apple-touch-icon"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter value="144x144" name="sizes"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter name="href" value="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
            </xp:parameter>
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
```

Answer (score 2):

The message "File does not exist" from your proxy shows that this request is actually *NOT* redirected. A successful proxy redirect would never result in revealing the proxy www directory path to a user. The fact that the error shows a full path indicates that your redirection failed. Time to revisit your proxy settings. Nothing to do on the Notes side.

Comment: That path is an error in server log and not displayed to the user. I had to go to the log to figure out why my image wouldn't display and found that. The user just sees a screenshot of the app/webpage as a bookmark instead of the intended png image.

Comment: It is still a redirection problem since your proxy looks for that file in its own data path

Comment: But then why does everything else work in the database as well as the page icon that is also in the Image Resources (see snip below) if it is a redirection problem? The only "broken" piece are these png images for bookmarks/webclips. <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
 xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
 xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" pageIcon="/AppIcon.png"
 pageTitle="Orders">

Comment: Add your redirection rule to the question and one can have a look. Then check the HTML source where the src property is pointing and if your redirection rule matches. I would be very surprised if that is a Domino setting.

Comment: In the HTML source code if you click/hover on the link to the image, it was found on the Domino server and redirected properly, but it just won't display on the iPhone or iPad. I am going to open a PMR with IBM to see if this is expected behavior. For now we put the png images on the proxy to get this application out the door.

Comment: You use an IBM proxy? What is your redirection expression?